# C - realloc with array of structs

Tags: c

I'm doing a array of structs to dynamic allocate a list of products but this works only for a few times (3~5 times) and then I got this error.

> *** Error in `./test': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x000055bc0b44f260 ***

Here is my code, this is part of a work for college.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int cod;
    float price;
} Product;

int main () {

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("products.txt", "r+");

    if(fp == NULL)
        fopen("products.txt", "w+");

    int control = 1;
    int choice;
    int tam = 0;
    int i;
    Product *p1;

    p1 = malloc(sizeof(Product));

    while(fread(&p1[0], sizeof(Product), 1, fp) != NULL){
        tam++;
    }

    if(tam > 1){
        rewind(fp);

        p1 = malloc((tam) * sizeof(*p1));

        for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++){
            fread(&p1[i], sizeof(Product), 1, fp);
        }
    }

    rewind(fp);

    do {
        printf("1 - Add product\n2 - Show all products\n3 - Exit\n-> ");
        scanf(" %d", &choice);

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                 if (tam == 0) {
                    //p1 = malloc(sizeof(Product));
                    printf("Digit the product code: ");
                    scanf(" %d", &p1[tam].cod);
                    printf("Digit the product price: ");
                    scanf(" %f", &p1[tam].price);
                    tam++;
                } else {
                    printf("***Realloqing: %d***\n", tam * sizeof(*p1));
                    p1 = (Product*)realloc(p1, (tam) * sizeof(Product));
                    for (i = tam; i > 0; i--) {
                        p1[i].cod = p1[i-1].cod;
                        p1[i].price = p1[i-1].price;
                    }
                    printf("Digit the product code: ");
                    scanf(" %d", &p1[0].cod);
                    printf("Digit the product price: ");
                    scanf(" %f", &p1[0].price);
                    tam++;
                }
            break;
            case 2:
                for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
                    printf("Product code: %d\nProduct price: %f\n", p1[i].cod, p1[i].price);
                }
            break;
            case 3:
                control = 0;
            break;
        }

    } while (control);

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        fwrite(&p1[i], sizeof(Product), 1, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    free(p1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A couple of things: First you should not assign back to the pointer you pass to `realloc`, if `realloc` fails and returns a null pointer you will lose the original pointer and have a memory leak. Then you should read [this discussion about casting `malloc` (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858).

Comment: As for your problem, it seems that you are writing out of bounds of the memory you allocate. You might want to use a tool such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help you find such problems.

Comment: `fopen("products.txt", "w+");` -> `fp = fopen("products.txt", "w+");`

Comment: @MichaelWalz thanks I hadn't seen it

Comment: `tam` is int, and `sizeof` yields `size_t` (an unsigned type). Be careful when doing things like `int * size_t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    printf("***Realloqing: %d***\n", tam * sizeof(*p1));
    p1 = (Product*)realloc(p1, tam * sizeof(Product));
```

When `tam` is, say 1, then you realloc `tam * sizeof(Product)`, but you need to realloc `(tam + 1) * sizeof(Product)`, because now you need space for **2** products.

So this fixes the problem:

```
    printf("***Realloqing: %d***\n", (tam + 1) * sizeof(*p1));
    p1 = (Product*)realloc(p1, (tam + 1) * sizeof(Product));
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
p1 = (Product*)realloc(p1, (tam) * sizeof(Product));
```

Violates the First Rule of Realloc, which is that you must not assign the result of realloc directly to the same variable which is passed as its first argument.  When you do, if it fails, you have lost (leaked) the old pointer.

Second, you do not check the return values from various functions, such as `malloc()`, `realloc()`, and `scanf()`.   This too is a cardinal sin.

If fixing all that still leaves you with a broken program, use valgrind.

Comment: Are you sure about the "First Rule of Realloc"? The [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html) says: _If the new size of the memory object would require movement of the object, the space for the previous instantiation of the object is freed._

Comment: @KeineLust: Yes I am sure.  Note that I said "if it fails."  You are assuming it succeeds.

Comment: Where can I read more about these First Rule etc, commandments?

Comment: Here, it still fails. BTW `realloc`, `malloc` etc. returning `NULL` is very unlikely to happen in toy programs.

Comment: @Anaboth, oh,  I just posted an answer, but yes that was the problem.